# Replacing modifier cards where the new card has a prerequisite for it to be played

Tags: gloom

A situation arose where an event was played that allowed the top modifier card on a character to be replaced with one from their hand, but the modifier they tried to play had a prerequisite that the character must have the Romance story icon, which they did not have.

The second edition rules directly mention that Continuous and Persistent effects will remain active on the new character for as long as the text is visible when they are moved. By extrapolation this means that Immediate effects will never trigger more than once since they only happen when the card is initially played. I would expect "moved" to also cover occasions where a card is replaced. However a prerequisite is an effect that has no type so doesn't have a direct mention in the rules.

So would the prerequisite be treated as a Continuous effect and thus must be adhered to when moving the card, or would the prerequisite be treated as a condition of the card being played and thus have no further effect when it is moved because it is essentially not being played now?

Answer (score 2):

The card in question has the text "This card can only be played on a Character with the (Romance) icon." This is a condition of the card being played. The situation you describe would not be a legal move. They would need to choose a different Modifier card from their hand.

Comment: But the card was not played - it was swapped on to a character - which is where the rules fall down in respect to this.

Comment: That is considered a play for the purposes of the prerequisite.